# Problem with implementing the binary search algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I am new to programming. I have six month that i have started learning programming and i trying to test my self with some algorithm. I am trying to implement the binary search algorithm. In theory I have grasped the concept but in implementation i am having some trouble.

Below is the algorithm implementation:

```
    public static boolean binarySearchNumber(int[] numbers, int number) {
        Arrays.sort(numbers);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
        int lowIndex = 0;
        int highIndex = numbers.length;
        while(lowIndex!=highIndex) {
            int midIndex = (lowIndex+highIndex)/2;
            if(numbers[midIndex]==number) {
                return true;
            } else if(numbers[midIndex]>number) {
                lowIndex = midIndex+1;
            } else if(numbers[midIndex]<number) {
                highIndex = midIndex-1;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The unit test

```
    @Test
    public void testBinarySearchNumber() {
        // setup
        int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 3, 55, 8, 22, 9, 11, 0 };
        // execute
        boolean found = ArrayUtil.binarySearchNumber(numbers, 8);
        System.out.println(found);

    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am trying to implement algorithm by myself to help create a programming logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beyond the error reported in the other answers, I found another one:

```
public static boolean binarySearchNumber(int[] numbers, int number) {
        Arrays.sort(numbers);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
        int lowIndex = 0;
        int highIndex = numbers.length;
        while (lowIndex != highIndex) {
            int midIndex = (lowIndex + highIndex) / 2;
            if (numbers[midIndex] == number) {
                return true;
            } else if (numbers[midIndex] < number) {
                lowIndex = midIndex + 1;
            } else if (numbers[midIndex] > number) {
                highIndex = midIndex ; // here
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

`midIndex` is in array, you don't need to subtract 1, otherwise you will always have one element less.

**EDIT**

Another manner to achieve the desired results is change the if condition as suggested by @Eran's answer.

Comment: Your `highIndex = midIndex ; // here` change is not required if you change the loop's condition and the initial value of `highIndex`, as in my answer.

Comment: @Eran I noticed the change in IF conditions only after replying. There was also another answer that only highlighted the "else if" problem and I assumed, at first glance, that your answer was similar. Anyway edited my answer, upvoted yours: the JDK implementation is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues:

```
public static boolean binarySearchNumber(int[] numbers, int number) {
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    int lowIndex = 0;
    int highIndex = numbers.length - 1; // the last index is numbers.length - 1
    while (lowIndex <= highIndex) { // you have to allow lowIndex to be equal to highIndex
                                    // or you'll fail to locate the lowest and highest numbers
        int midIndex = (lowIndex+highIndex)/2;
        if(numbers[midIndex]==number) {
            return true;
        } else if(numbers[midIndex] < number) { // you used the wrong comparison operator here
            lowIndex = midIndex+1;
        } else if(numbers[midIndex] > number) { // you used the wrong comparison operator here
            highIndex = midIndex-1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Out of curiosity, I looked at the JDK implementation of binary search in `Arrays` class, and it is very similar to my solution (apart from the JDK's method returning the index instead of a `boolean`).

```
private static int binarySearch0(long[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex,
                                 long key) {
    int low = fromIndex;
    int high = toIndex - 1; // that's equivalent to a.length - 1 if we search the whole array

    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) >>> 1; // that's equivalent to (low + high) / 2
        long midVal = a[mid];

        if (midVal < key)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if (midVal > key)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            return mid; // key found
    }
    return -(low + 1);  // key not found.
}
```

Comment: This also solves the error. I would vote this up. But i don't have priveleges to do so. Thanks a lot for you effort.

Comment: Thank you Eran. I voted your question up. This is also a correct solution of binary search algorithm.